# Google Chrome random pictures?

Tags: google-chrome

I opened up Google Chrome one day and it was showing random pictures where there shouldn't be any. Is something wrong?

Comment: Do you have any Chrome extensions installed? A buggy extension could be causing the problem. Try disabling extensions one by one and see if that fixes the problem. Instructions for doing that are here: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187443

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of this happening?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Answer (score -1):

1. Uninstall chrome
2. Clean registry ([Ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) is way good enough for this task)
3. Re-install chrome.

Note: remember to backup your bookmarks, favourites, passwords etc.

your chrome data may be hijacked, or your registry may be faulty.

seen this happen before, solved it with these very steps.
(i checked your Yahoo question)